# Watch AppleTV and XBOX One on my LG UltraFine 5k / MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, appletv, thunderbolt, hdmi

I have searched high and low, but can't find a good solution. Any help is appreciated!

I have a MacBook Pro 2016 w/TB. I have the LG UltraFine 5k monitor, which I absolutely love. The resolution, color, and brightness are stellar. I knew I would be limited with this monitor in terms of video connections--just one TB3 port.

I have reached my pain point and would like to see if there is a way to use other things with it. I have an XBOX One and an AppleTV that I would like to be able to view on my monitor, but of course, that means that it has to somehow go through my MBP.

I assume that there is no adapter that will permit the LG UltraFine's TB3 port to accept HDMI. Is this true?

I assume that a TB or USB HDMI capture device won't work with the AppleTV due to HDCP. From what I have read, it would work with gameplay on the XBOX, though. But, I'm guessing that if connects the AppleTV to the HDMI input on the XBOX, it will enable HDCP. I'm also worried about the lag that such a setup would introduce. I'm not a super gamer, so a little lag would be acceptable, but I'm not sure it would even be ploayable.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Is there even a possibility to make this work?